# How to get content-type from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-type

Is there a way to get the content-type of an iframe's content inside the load event handler function attached to it?

Answer (score 2):

i assume this should do the work using jquery

```
$('iframe').contents().contentType
```

in the load event *this* should point to the iframe dom so

```
$(this).contentType
```

should work

Comment: Both ways returns me 'undefined'. But I know where you are going, you are getting the contentType property from the document DOM element. Why the content() method doesn't return the document DOM element? I have found an alternative way of getting the document element using raw javascript, but I would like to do it using jQuery.